# Stationarity of log industrial index and log CPI

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, time-series

I'm looking to estimate a VAR, one of the variables in this VAR is the log of industrial production, and another is the log of the consumer price index. Will I need to difference these to get consistent estimates? Or will leaving them as is be fine?

Comment: This depends on your data. Why don't you run some tests? Augmented Dickey Fuller and KPSS?

Comment: Also always plot your data. You can usually tell pretty quickly if the series is non-stationary by looking at it.